# mongoose .save() method don't insert the data to MonogoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i do these steps in console

1. node
2. .load app.js
3. Massage.save()

then in mongoDB shell

1. use test
2. db.test.find()

and when i check the data base, it's empty

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  year: Number,
  score: Number,
});

// Models
const Movie = new mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema);

const Massage = new Movie({
  title: "The Massage",
  year: 1976,
  score: 92,
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("ss");
});

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I did not set a collection in the model

so instead of

```
const Movie = new mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema);
```

it should be

```
const Movie = new mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema, collectionName);
```

when you want to extract the data from database

```
use database // go to the database u want 

db.collection.find() // extract the data from the collection
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the most important part:

```
const Massage = await new Movie({
  title: "The Massage",
  year: 1976,
  score: 92,
}).save();
```

Comment: how to fix this error? Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Wrap the function with async